# desktop at a remote location

Tags: remote-desktop

I visited a friend's firm yesterday where they exclusively use Linux and one of the things that they implemented is that everyone's actual desktop / machine (they are a team of 20 people) are at some remote data-center and on their office PC they merely logon to their desktops and can view their environments as if they are working off a local PC. It wasn't like Windows' Remote Desktop (which essentially pops up a window on one desktop that shows a different PC's desktop), but in their entire desktop itself appears for the first time after log in as if it was always there (but really it resides at the remote location).

What is this concept called?

They were using a variety of Linux, but mostly Red Hat.

Comment: A [thin client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client)?

Comment: Or a [virtual desktop infrastructure (VDI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization#Virtual_desktop_infrastructure)

Comment: thanks. the definition of VDI seems to match what they have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [VDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization#Virtual_desktop_infrastructure), as larsks noted - the bits on the local desk can be either [thin clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client) or full-fledged desktop machines.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an implementation of the Linux Terminal Server Project, similar to windows terminal server, but without all the licensing garbage and more awesomeness.

http://www.ltsp.org/